# A recursion involving binomial coefficients: looking for a q-analog

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, q-analogs

Let $a_n := \frac{1}{2n+1}\binom{3n}{n}$.
Then it is known that (one can find references in the OEIS for this.)
$$
a_n = \sum_{\substack{i,j,k \geq 0 \\ i+j+k=n-1} } a_i a_j a_k.
$$

Is there a natural q-analog of this recursion for the corresponding q-binomials?
That is, define the q-analog $b_n := \frac{1}{[2n+1]_q}\binom{3n}{n}_q$.
Is there some suitable function $f$ (depending on $i,j,k$) such that
the following holds:
$$
b_n = \sum_{\substack{i,j,k \geq 0 \\ i+j+k=n-1} }q^{f(i,j,k)} b_i b_j b_k.
$$

EDIT: With the connection with Catalan numbers,
the analogous questions is, with $c_n := \frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$
is there a q-analog of the classical recursion
$$
c_n = \sum_{\substack{i,j \geq 0 \\ i+j=n-1} } c_i c_j ?
$$
And, this is as far as I know, there is no q-analog of this recursion, compatible with the q-analog of $c_n$.

Essentially: This amounts to choosing between the Carlitz (q-analog of recursion), or the q-binomial version of q-Catalan numbers.

Comment: These are (the first case of) Fuss-Catalan numbers, right? "q-Fuss-Catalan" gets some hits on Google...

Comment: As mentioned, it's in the OEIS-- https://oeis.org/A001764

Comment: @SamHopkins Ah, yes. A good reference seem to be https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03024089 where the recursion is (0.1), for p=3.